# C#: Winforms Progress Bar

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom progress bar on my main form (UI thread). I create a background thread to read input data from a CSV file (on a menu click), and I update the value of the progress bar using anonymous delegate. Everything works great the first time only.

If I repeat the read data process (from menu click), the data reads in as it should (I dump it to a console as it is being read), but the progress bar does not show up at all. Am I missing something here?

Essentially the progress bar works only once and then does not show up if I repeat the read operation.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I am using the code essentially from William Daniel. Here it is:

```
class CustomProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public CustomProgressBar()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        // None... Helps control the flicker.
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        const int inset = 2;
        using (Image offscreenImage = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics offscreen = Graphics.FromImage(offscreenImage))
            {
                offscreen.Clear(Color.DarkBlue);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

                if (ProgressBarRenderer.IsSupported)
                    ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(offscreen, rect);

                rect.Inflate(new Size(-inset, -inset));  // Deflate inner rectangle
                rect.Width = (int)(rect.Width * ((double)this.Value / this.Maximum));
                if (rect.Width == 0) rect.Width = 1;
                LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0),
                      new Point(0, Height - inset * 2), BackColor, ForeColor);
                offscreen.FillRectangle(brush, inset, inset, rect.Width, rect.Height);

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(offscreenImage, 0, 0);
                offscreenImage.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The usage code is:

```
 // ... update progress bar value
 this.pBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
 {
     this.pBar.Value = (int) ( ((double) nRows) * 100.0 / ((double) fileLines) );
 });
```

I also use this.pBar.Show() to show it and I also hide it using this.pBar.Hide().

Comment: Showing some code would be really helpful here.

Comment: To see the code would be helpful. As a general answer: there must be state in your application that probably isn't reset.

Comment: Not enough information here -- can you post code?

Comment: Would be better if you used the standard progress bar until you get the basic app working. Otherwise everyone will question your custom bar

Comment: Be sure you reset the progress bar once your done with it.  Debug the code, figure out the reason its not working, find where it is failing.

Comment: If by reset you mean set its value to zero, I do that.

Comment: FWIW it's just easier to write `nRows*100/fileLines`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that other thread always updates the progress bar through [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method. I'm not sure if that's what you meant by "I update the value of the progress bar using anonymous delegate"?

Also, did you remember to reset the progress bar's [position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value.aspx) before the second run?

Comment: I do this. I use // ... reset progress bar to minimum value
this.pBar.Value = this.pBar.Minimum;